# SQL date time value format

Tags: javascript, mysql

i have a SQL field in table

which looks like this

```
 `updatedAt` datetime(6) NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `createdAt` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
```

Now, When I am trying to enter the value this is what error SQL is giving me

> "sqlMessage": "Incorrect datetime value: 'Sat, 03 Aug 2019' for
>   column 'createdAt' at row 1",

This is the value I am passing for createdAt

```
'Sat, 03 Aug 2019'
```

created using this

```
const dateString = new Date().toUTCString().split(' ').slice(0, 4).join(' ');
```

I have also tried `Date.now()` but same error

> "sqlMessage": "Incorrect datetime value: '1564834662852' for column
>   'createdAt' at row 1",

This is the first time I am working with SQL, Can someone help me in figuring out what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Why not submit a valid datetime instead, e.g. '2019-08-03'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just update your schema for setting default datetime

```
createdAt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, updatedAt DATETIME ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

or

if you don't want to use default timestamps in your table you can / should datetime format in your date in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS` format which is expected by Mysql.
for that you can use

```
const dateString = new Date().toISOString().substring(0,19).replace('T',' ');

output: "2019-08-03 13:19:41"
```